# css anchor fill entire list element

Tags: css, html-lists, anchor, css-tables

I have this menu that I have been working on for a while.  I am using the CSS table displays to accomplish it.  When the text inside of my links take up two lines, the ones that are only one line will not fill the parent li on hover.  Is there any way I am missing that can accomplish this?

http://jsfiddle.net/g7jmh567/

css

```
.menu {
  background-color: #687c9e;
  display: table;
}

 .menu-list {
   display: table-row;
 }

.menu-list > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.125rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-list > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.25rem 1.25rem 1.25rem 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 2.25rem;
}

.menu-list > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #7889a8;
}

.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

html

```
 <nav class="content menu">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">A really long</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Some really long word</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Special Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Photo Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't really understand, can you please elaborate more ? what functionality are you looking for ? how do you want this navigation to appear ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the links on hover, to all fill the parent li, and subsequently the entire height of the menu, no matter how many rows of text there are in the anchor link. You may have to resize the fiddle to get the longer elements to be two rows.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry but I don't get your point ! any visualization ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of horrible at explaining.  Here it is with the hover color applied permanently on two elements. http://jsfiddle.net/708d15v1/1/  . The "some really long word" link is taking up the full container of the parent li, the "home" link on the other hand is not.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the padding from your `li`, and add it to your `menu-list`, check out the link below;

[Nav](https://jsfiddle.net/708d15v1/2/)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Seven year old response but still pointed me in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it didn't fill the entire li 'coz you're just filling the `anchor`

hover the `li` instead of the `anchor`

```
.menu-list > li:hover {
  background-color: #7889a8;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ft6fakdg/)

Comment: Yeah, that was one way I could do it.  I was trying to get it on the anchor though since I was going to do the checkbox trick on the anchor and needed to target it, since there is no way to target the checkbox's parent. I was trying to do a noscript fallback.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

See This link: this may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/guruWork/8fwo0r06/2/

```
<nav class="content menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">
          <li><a href=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>A really long</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Some really long word</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Special Events</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Newsletter</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Photo Gallery</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

And CSS

```
.menu {
  background-color: #687c9e;
}

.menu-list {
  display: table;padding:0; margin:0;width:100%;
}

.menu-list > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-list > li > a {
  display: table;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:53px; text-align:center;
}
.menu-list > li > a span{display: table-cell;padding: 5% .5rem;vertical-align: middle;}
.menu-list > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #7889a8;
}

.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```